# Same hierarchical block for different power supplies in Altium Designer

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, schematics, altium, hardware

I need to repeat one circuit in my design but connecting it to different power supplies. Because it is a repetition (iteration) I have decided to use a hierarchical block and copy it 3 times. The thing is that I don't know how to connect the power lines. If I connect the three power options (vcc1, Vcc2 and Vcc3) as sheet entries and ports, Altium is not working well, it connects things that are not supposed to be connected in the project. If I use power ports (global) it will work but I cannot repeat the same block.

This does not work:
[image]

This works but will not allow me to repeat the block in the highest sheet (I cannot change the power supply options)(power ports are global)(I would need three different sheets with almost the same circuit, just changing the power signals):
[image]

Comment: Could you please show the actual schematic sheets?

Comment: It is confidential, what do you want to know? I can tell you the details.